# How do I have a git tag checked out on my hosted web server

Tags: git, github, web-hosting

I have been developing a web application and using git for the project. Until now I have been running it on my local machine. Now that I want to check it out on my hosted web server I thought of creating a tag. So used `git tag -a v0.1 -m 'version0.1'` command for it. Command `git tag` lists the tag that I have just created. Now the question is how do I have(checkout) this tag on my web server?

My hosted web server understands git commands. I would like to know a command or procedure to have this tag on my server. There wont be any development going on the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a simple way. There's no need to define a new remote.

- Step 1: On local machine (after committing your code) simply do:

```
    $ git tag -a vx.x.x -m "version x.x.x"
    $ git push --tags
```

- Step 2: Then on hosted server, navigate to the folder where you have to checkout then do:

```
    $ git clone git@github.com:username/proj.git
    $ cd proj
    $ git checkout vx.x.x
```

Now, if you have to create another tag for next version let's say x.x.y, then repeat Step 1 above replacing x.x.x with x.x.y and replace Step 2 with following.

- Step 2: On hosted server do the following.

```
    $ cd proj
    $ git fetch --tags
    $ git checkout vx.x.y
```

Answer (score 2):

I understand that you would like to have a git tag local repository copy onto your hosted web server . Also you have mentioned that your hosted web server is setup to understand git commands.

Now on your local machine, define a name for the remote webserver and push the tag :

```
$ git remote add myHostedWebServer ssh://server.example.org/path/toyour/website.git

$ git push --tags myHostedWebServer
```

Hope this helps

**Updated :**
The way I understood your question, you wanted to push your local changes directly on to your hosted web server. If so you could follow the steps mentioned above. However now that you have mentioned you have your code on github and would prefer to update your web host server from your github, there are several ways, one of them being:

- On your local machine do : `$git push myDefinedName master`
- As you have mentioned that your host server understands git commands
  and assuming that you have git init --bare to create the repository ,
  navigate to your hosted web server directory associated with git and do:

  `$git pull myDefinedName master`

  `$git checkout <tag name>`

  Alternatively you can use post-receive hooks. You can get more detailed info [here](http://toroid.org/ams/git-website-howto)

Comment: Hey user1316, I have my code on github. So can I use your command in the following format? `$git remote add myDefinedName git@github.com:username/Hello-World.git`. And also, After I run this on my local machine, what commands should I execute on my host server in order to have tag v0.1 there? (I am sorry as this might be silly, but I am unaware since I am completely new to git).

Comment: I am going to update the answer, keeping the additional information provided above.